# Vue component updated (rerendered) without reason

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a component which is being updated (rerendered) without reason when parent's data item is changed even though it has nothing to do with component in question.

This is a simple reproduction https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-cannon-s6jgp?file=/public/index.html if anyone can shed some light on this. (clicking button will fire update event in component)

If I remove element whose class is changed by vue (or remove dynamic class) it works as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because at each render you define new objects for the `something` property:

```html
<hello-world :something="[{prop: 'vvv'},{prop: 'rrr'}]"></hello-world>
```

- By clicking the button, you update the global data. The root element is rerendered.
- During render, a new array with new objects is created as assigned at the `something` property in your component. While the objects created at each render are equal, they are different (i.e. they map to a different memory point)
- Your component finds that the property `something` changes its reference, so it re-renders.

If you create an `items` property in your data and you pass that reference as the prop, the component is not re-rendered again:

main.js:

```js
data: {
    active: false,
    items: [{ prop: "vvv" }, { prop: "rrr" }]
  },
```

index.html:

```html
<hello-world :something="items"></hello-world>
```

Note that this behavior occurs because you are passing an `array` 8and it would be the same with an `object`. It would not happen with a constant variable of the primitive types (such as string, int, boolean, float), such as `:something="'string'"`

Comment: Thanks for this, I didn't expect root comp. to rerender everything for a simple class change :|

Comment: Well, how can it know what needs to update without scanning the structure?

Comment: I get the scanning part but not the rerender part for parts of html which didn't change. Nevertheless, In my case it was header with toggle and it is now a separate component so there is no more rerendering of other parts.